# Get total price of products in checkout (cart) page (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to get and display the total price of items in the cart page added by customer.

Goal: The customer should be able to observe changing total price of the order. The problem is that customer can increase or decrease quantity.

I have an array of "OrderLine" objects taken from the session storage. Each of them has quantity and priceWhenBought.

```
@SessionStorage({key: 'cart'}) orderLineMealsInCart: Array<OrderLine> = [];
```

and here is OrderLine class:

```
export class OrderLine {
  mealId?: number;
  meal?: Meal;
  orderId?: number;
  quantity: number;
  priceWhenBought: number;
}
```

In the html file is input which controls the quantity of the item in real-time and there is a method bound to this input which changes the item with "old" quantity for the item with changed quantity after you write a different number.

```
<div *ngFor="let orderLineMeal of orderLineMealsInCart">
<div class="cartMealsSection">

  <div *ngFor="let meal of mealsForImage">
    <div *ngIf="meal.id === orderLineMeal.mealId">
      <img src="{{meal.picture}}" alt="" class="cartMeal-picture">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>{{orderLineMeal.mealId}}</div>
  <div>{{orderLineMeal.priceWhenBought}}</div>
  <div>{{orderLineMeal.quantity}}</div>
  <div>{{orderLineMeal.quantity * orderLineMeal.priceWhenBought}}</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <button (click)="deleteOrderLineMealFromCart(orderLineMeal)">Delete</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
    <input type="number" matInput [(ngModel)]="orderLineMeal.quantity" (ngModelChange)="changeOrderLineMeal(orderLineMeal)">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then the method for changing the quantity:

```
    changeOrderLineMeal(orderLineMeal: OrderLine) {
    const index = this.orderLineMealsInCart.indexOf(orderLineMeal);
    this.orderLineMealsInCart[index] = orderLineMeal;
    (<any>this.orderLineMealsInCart).save(); // <- saving to the session storage
  }
```

I know that for real-time changing total price of the order I need Observable (rxjs) but in this case, I don't have a clue how to achieve this.

I will put here also Order class where you can find totalPrice of the order, the last thing I need to implement.

```
export class Order {
  id?: number;
  mobilenumber: string;
  customerName: string;
  pickUpDateAndTime?: Date;
  orderedDateAndTime?: Date;
  comment: string;
  orderLines?: OrderLine[];
  totalPrice:  number;
}
```

I will be thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need calculate the total using reduce. You can use a getter

```
  get total()
  {
    return this.items.reduce((sum,x)=>
    ({quantity:1,
      priceWhenBought:sum.priceWhenBought+x.quantity*x.priceWhenBought}),
    {quantity:1,priceWhenBought:0}).priceWhenBought;
  }

  //In your .html
  {{total}}
```

**Brief explain**
about using a getter is only that you can referred in the html to a variable like

```
{{myvariable}}
```

If you use a getter . That's a function that begin by get, show the result of the function

```
{{myget}}
get myget()
{
    return "Hello word";
}
```

About reduce:

reduce has three arguments. This arguments must be of the same type of the array. So if our array is an array of object, the three arguments must be the same type. The first argument is the "acumulator", the second argument is the element of the array and the thrid argument is the "initial value". The "transform" element must be of the same type too

So, if our array is an array of numbers whe can do

```
[1,4,7,2].reduce((sum,x,0)=>(sum+x))
```

If we have an array of elements like

```
this.total2=[
      {x:1},
      {x:4},
      {x:7},
      {x:2}
    ].reduce((sum,x)=>({x:sum.x+x.x}))  //total2 will be{x:14}
```

See that it's of the way reduce((< T >,< T >)=>(< T >))
Our element can be so complex we want, e.g.

```
this.total2=[
  {x:1,y:3},
  {x:4,y:4},
  {x:7,y:5},
  {x:2,y:6}
].reduce((sum,x)=>({x:sum.x+x.x,y:sum.y+x.y})) //return {x:14,y:18}
```

Again look the "result" must be an object with property x and y. If you don't feed reduce with the third argument, reduce take the first element of the array and iterate over the others. It is the reason because if we make some like

```
this.total2=[
  {x:2,y:3},
  {x:4,y:4},
  {x:7,y:5},
  {x:2,y:6}
].reduce((sum,x)=>({x:sum.x+x.x*x.y,y:1})) //return {x:65,y:1}
  //return 2+4*4+7*5+2*6 ¡¡at first sum={x:2,y:3}, but not use the "y"
  //to calculate the product: is NOT 2*3

//So, we need add the third argument
 .reduce((sum,x)=>({x:sum.x+x.x*x.y,y:1}),{x:0,y:0})
```

Comment: Could you please very shortly describe or explain the syntax? I somehow cannot understand it.

Comment: I updated my answer with a "brief" explain. As reduce need object of type {quantity:##,priceWhenBrougth:##} I use the property priceWhenBrought as acumulator of the product of quantity*price

Comment: Thank you so much for effort and explanation!!! You helped me a lot! There is a special place in Heaven for people like you :D